# Android Studio and Odoo (Open ERP)

Tags: android-studio, odoo

I would like to connect a mobile app to Odoo.
How do we connect android studio to Odoo (OpenERP)?

Answer (score 2):

Android studio to my knowledge really does not connect to Odoo. You can create an app which interacts with Odoo via `xmlrpc` or `jsonrpc` as well as `http` requests to [controllers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html). Odoo has a [mobile framework](https://www.odoo.com/slides/slide/odoo-mobile-development-framework-app-build-with-it-199) if you would prefer to work with it however this is not necessary to develop and android app that interacts with Odoo. Here is the [github project](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework)

Comment: Consider looking at [OdooJsonRpcClient ](github.com/kasim1011/OdooJsonRpcClient) for Android.